# How to update keycloak user without keycloak admin client?

Tags: java, keycloak

I'm writing custom REST endpoint.
When I call my Resource I trying to update some users in keycloak by getting instanse of UserResource class.
But after updating first one user transaction in KeycloakTransactionManager is closing and after what im getting exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot access delegate without a transaction.

I tried to begin transaction by:
(for example)

```java
KeycloakSession session = ... ; //got it from context
if(!session.getTransactionManager().isActive()){
session.getTransactionManager().begin();
}
```

But got "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction in illegal state for rolleback: FINISHED" and after that "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction associated with the current thread".

```java
// custom resource class
public class MyResource {

    @Context
    private HttpHeaders headers;

    private MyAdminAuth auth;
    private MyHelper helper;
    private AppAuthManager authManager;
// I've correctly getting session and with open/active transaction
    private KeycloakSession session;

    public MyResource(KeycloakSession session) {
        this.authManager = new AppAuthManager();
        this.session = session;
    }

@Path("sync-users-run")
    @POST
    @NoCache
    @ResponseObject
    public String syncUsersRun(String json) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        helper = new MyHelper(authManager, session, headers);
        SyncMain sync = new SyncMain(params, helper);
        String response = gson.toJson(sync.run());
        return response;
    }
}


private boolean updateUserInKeycloak(UserRepresentation existingUser, User newData) {
        existingUser.setEmail(newData.getEmail());
        existingUser.setEnabled(newData.isActive());
        existingUser.setFirstName(newData.getName());
        existingUser.setLastName(newData.getLastName());
        try {
            KeycloakSession session = helper.getSession();

            UserModel user = session.users().getUserById(existingUser.getId(), helper.getRealmFromSession(session));
            UserResource userResource = helper.getInstanceOfUserResource(user, MyAdminAuth.ROLE_ALLOW_SYNC_USERS);

//trying to update user but it works only for the first one
            Response response = userResource.updateUser(existingUser);
            if (response.getStatus() != NO_CONTENT_CODE) {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException | WebApplicationException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

How can I update users without keycloak admin client corretly?
Maybe exist more easy and right way?